# Нужно выделить объекты с нужной толщиной

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет. Я имею простой код, который с помощью skimage threshold_minimum выделяет линии. Да, возможно, это не идеальный метод. Тем не менее на полученном изображении мне нужно выделить линии, у которых толщина меньше определенного значения пикселей. То есть я ожидаю, что указав значение в 3 пикселя часть линий на изображении будет удалено. Как вариант рассматривал cv2.HoughLines, но он рисует только ровные линии.

Код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, threshold_mean, threshold_minimum, try_all_threshold

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('C:\\temp\\map.png', 0)

thresh_min = threshold_minimum(img)
binary_min = img > thresh_min

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 3))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Original')

ax[1].imshow(binary_min, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('Thresholded (min)')

plt.show()
```

Результирующая картинка
[image: Результат]

Comment: Попробуйте морфологические операции типа открытие/закрытие